# with Kotlin, can you convert a Google Storage URL (GS://) to HTTPS?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage, picasso

In trying to use Glide and Picasso i have seen that they require a `HTTPS://` string input. i have tested and it works fine. But if I use a `GS://` which you get from a `Storage Reference` then the image does not load.

Is there a way to convert a `GS://` to a `HTTPS://`?

if this is not the correct way to be reading from firebase storage then how am I meant to retrieve the image from firebase?

Comment: Not quite sure what this has to do specifically with Kotlin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a gs:// URL in Cloud Storage, and you want to display that with Glide, you can use the [FirebaseUI Storage library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage#using-firebaseui-to-download-and-display-images) provided by the Firebase team.  After you have it properly integrated, you can simply pass the gs URL to Glide, and it will then know how to download the image for display.

As far as I know, there is no equivalent for Picasso.

You can also use [getDownloadUrl on a StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) to get an HTTPS download URL that will work in any case.

Comment: Thanks Doug, the second option you provided is actually the easier route and the option I ended up going with!